# Swift Animation on flipped Lable

Tags: ios, animation

I have a problem in Swift 2 that I can't fix...

I have a `UILabel` and a `UIView` that are both upside down. I added an extension to `UIView` to perform an animation (grow then shrink) that is performed when I click on a button. But when the animations are performed, the `UILabel` turns back by 180° during the animation whereas the `UIView` does not... Any idea about why is this happening ?

Here is the code:

`UIView's` extension:

```
func animateBounce(multiplier: CGFloat, duration: NSTimeInterval)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration / 2, animations:
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(multiplier, multiplier)
    }, completion:
    {
        finish in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration / 2)
        {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }
    })
}
```

How I flip the `UIView` and `UILabel`:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
```

How I call the animation:

```
let multiplier = 1.5 as CGFloat
let animationTime = 0.5 as NStimeInterval

label.animateBounce(1.5, duration: animationTime)
view.animateBounce(1.5, duration: animationTime)
```

ANSWER: (credits to matt)
I was overwriting the transform property of the label, thus removing the previous transformation (the rotation). You should use `CGAffineTransformConcat` to add add a new transform without removing the previous ones.

Comment: PS: Anybody knows why the first line of my post saying "Hello everybody,\n" won't show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(multiplier, multiplier)
```

and

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

Those lines specify the *whole* transform that `self` will have. Thus, they remove *all existing* transforms, including the transform that originally turned the label upside down, replacing them with the transforms you specify.

If that isn't what you want to do, don't do that. For example, instead of calling `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`, call `CGAffineTransformScale`, which lets you *start* with the *existing* transform on your view and *concatenate* a scale transform to that.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't think about that ! Seems legit thanks. Then what should I do ?  `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)` ?  EDIT: `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)` does the same thing.

Comment: Your code is silly. There is no need to chain two animations. Just do an autoreversing animation. — Meanwhile, I believe I've answered your question. You asked: "Any idea about why is this happening"; I've explained why.

Comment: I tried using the `.AutoReverse` option or `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)`, but the problem persists... I have no idea about how can I do that... Do you have any other things that can force the View to return to its original frame?

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't complete enough. This line is wrong too: `self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(multiplier, multiplier)` You are _setting_ the transform, which also means _removing_ the upside-down rotation transform you have already applied. What you want to do is apply a transform that is a combination of the existing rotation and newly added scale. Do you see? Then that autoreverses to the bare rotation, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks ! I understood the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

flip a label when the data changes
swift 4.

I have flipped a label from top to bottom                                                        **where my label is declared as**:

`@IBOutlet var cartCountLbl: UILabel!`                                   **in "viewDidLoad()".**

Call the function with this method

`self.perform(#selector(self.flip), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)`                                         **the flip method is declared as**:

```
    @objc func flip() {
        let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromTop, .showHideTransitionViews] 
        UIView.transition(with: cartCountLbl, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        })
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer further?

Comment: I have changed my answer you will understand it now @SirPeople